# How can I use the CEX REST API to place a market order?

Tags: python-3.x, rest, cryptocurrency

The [documentation](https://cex.io/rest-api) for the CEX exchange's REST API is quite good but it only says how to place limit orders as far as I can tell. You have to specify the price at which you want to purchase, e.g. Bitcoin, what if I just want to pay whatever the market price is? I know how to use the requests module on python to interact with a REST API.